# Opencv and python get document correct contur and draw on image

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Using opencv with python here is the output of document conture [image]

I'm using `opencv_python-4.2.0.34` the bottom left corner is not sharp as the other corners. How to make it right? (edit the bottom left corner automatically to look sharp, as off the others as arise)

here are the code to draw the contour:

```
img = cv2.imread(imagePath)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
invGamma = 1.0 / 0.3
table = np.array([((i / 255.0) ** invGamma) * 255
                  for i in np.arange(0, 256)]).astype("uint8")

# apply gamma correction using the lookup table
gray = cv2.LUT(gray, table)

ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(gray, 80, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

contours, hierachy = cv2.findContours(thresh1, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# except:
#     print('exception occurred')

def biggestRectangle(conts):
    biggest = None
    max_area = 0
    indexReturn = -1
    for index in range(len(conts)):
        i = conts[index]
        area = cv2.contourArea(i)
        if area > 100:
            peri = cv2.arcLength(i, True)
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(i, 0.1 * peri, True)
            if area > max_area and len(approx) == 4:
                biggest = approx
                max_area = area
                indexReturn = index
    return indexReturn

indexReturn = biggestRectangle(contours)
hull = cv2.convexHull(contours[indexReturn])

print(indexReturn)
print(contours[indexReturn])
print(hull)

# copyImg = img.copy()

cv2.imwrite(os.path.join('path_to_save', imageName),
            cv2.drawContours(img, [hull], 0, (0, 255, 0), 3))
```

How to make it right. I tried with another approach:

```
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(hull)

    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    newImageName = imageName.split('.')
    newImageName = newImageName[0] + '_rect.' + newImageName[1]
    print(newImageName)
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join('path_to_save', newImageName), img)
```

but it's giving me this (the blue outline):
[image]

Which is also wrong. How to correct it?

Comment: What do you mean by sharp in the first place? Be more specific, if you can; attach a ground truth of the desired contour.

Comment: I see you build a `convex_hull`, simply while traversing the `hull`, avoid consecutive points which have a big angle, and interpolate, that may give you only the sharp corners.

Comment: and how should  do that? Please provide a code sample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you know that the contour you are interested in is a piece of paper, maybe you can use a more systematic approach to find the largest rotated rectangle using OpenCV's `cv2.minAreaRect` ([link](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minarearect#minarearect)). It will return the center, size, and rotation of the rectangle that most tightly encloses your contour. Since your image has a pretty difficult background, I had to apply a few more processing steps using [OpenCV's morphologyEx function](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html) before grabbing the contours, but this this code I could see a better output (shown below).

```
# first, do some processing
kernel1 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (27, 27))
kernel2 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (13, 13))
thresh1 = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh1, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, kernel1)
thresh1 = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh1, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel2)

# find all contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh1, cv2.RETR_LIST, 
                                       cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# Find the largest ('max' using the key of the contour area)
biggest_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# Calculate the minimum enclosing rectangle: format ((x, y), (length, width), angle)
rectangle = cv2.minAreaRect(biggest_contour)

# conver the minAreaRect output to points
pts = cv2.boxPoints(rectangle)
# contours must be of shape (n, 1, 2) and dtype integer
pts = pts.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
pts = pts.astype(int)

# draw contours and display
cv2.drawContours(img, [pts], -1, (255, 0, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow('img', img)
k = cv2.waitKey(0)
```

output:
[image]

Comment: is there any way to improve it? The arm of Quadrilateral doesn't need to be parallel, like the previous one. Actually i just need to fix the curved shape only. so from x2,y2 to the left and from x1,y1 to the bottom, I wan't use line like that, then I will use four point transform (which will depend on the conture) to transform the image. (I've the code for the transform)

Comment: If you can get a better image that doesn't include your hand covering part of the image, that would help get the rectangle better

Comment: I just want to draw a Quadrilateral, which sides may not be parallel, but with sharp corners, is it possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I am aware, OpenCV does not have a function which allows you to approximate a contour with a contour of a fixed number of points. The only option is to use `approxPolyDP`, which you have shown in your question.